# SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() always returns true

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, ios9, storekit

It is important to check are In-App Purchases enabled to block UI properly, RayWenderlich blog says:

> Apple requires that you handle this situation gracefully; not doing so will likely result in an app rejection.

When you disable In-App Purchase, the Restrictions `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` should return `false` but it always returns `true` no matter what. I tried with 2 different projects, including, [this one from RayWenderlich.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started)

I tested this only with iOS 9.

How to recognise that In-App Purchases disabled with parental restrictions?

**Update.**
Somebody requested to share my code. I don't think it is necessary, the code is obvious and doesn't have errors. I can reproduce this problems with the Ray's project too.

```
// This function is called in from viewDidLoad()
// And after SKProduct is updated.
func addTextFromProduct(p: SKProduct) {

    if let title = p.localizedTitle as String? {
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
    }

    if let description = p.localizedDescription as String? {
        if dailyLimit {
            self.informationLabel.text? = "\(waitingTime)\(description)"
        } else {
            self.informationLabel.text? = "\(description)"
        }

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            unblockButtons()
        }

    } else {
        self.informationLabel.text? = "\(waitingTime)\(description)\n\nIn-App Purchase is unavailable at this moment."
        blockButtons()
    }

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        self.priceFormatter.locale = p.priceLocale
        let localPrice: String! = self.priceFormatter.stringFromNumber(p.price)
        let label = "\(localPrice)"
        self.buyButton.setTitle(label, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        blockButtons()
        buyButton.setTitle("Not Available", forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, under previous versions of iOS however the canMakePayments correctly returns false if InAppPurchases are restricted, however on iOS 9 it seems to reflect the Install Apps restriction?

Comment: Confirmed, Xcode 7.2.1, iOS 9.2.1, ARC enabled canMakePayments only returns false when Install Apps is restricted after loading app.  Here is a helpful link for how to set and play around with restrictions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204396.  Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

You need to check in your `viewDidLoad` method if the user has enabled IAP.

```
if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {

            print("IAP is enabled, loading")

            // Your Products


            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()



        }
        else {

         print("IAP not allowed")  
         //Do something like show an alert, the user has not allowed in app purchases

       }
```

Comment: Yes I know about this, my problem that's my app thinks In-App Purchases are enabled, even if I disable them in Settings > General > Restrictions.

Comment: If you know about this then post some code so people can assist you.  If you have this code implemented posting it would have told us that. If you want assistance show what you have done so far and tried

Comment: Move  `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments`,  to `viewwillAppear`  and log the events with both  scenarios, no other code just the logs to find out what your getting there

Comment: I logged it in `viewWillAppear` - it always returns `true.`

Comment: Have not tested on previous version of iOS but on version 9 in my case always return true